# How to import more than one million data into CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I am using "SheetConnection" and "SheetRead" for importing my data into CPLEX.
The size of data that I am importing is more than what is allowed by excel (excel limit is one million). I would like to know what are the possible ways, commands for importing data into CPLEX which allows for importing around 3 million data. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use a spreadsheet for anything as big as that. They are fantastic tools that I use every day, but they are NOT intended or designed to handle data that large very efficiently. USE a **DATABASE**! Since you are probably on a version of Windows, you can probably use the basic version of SQL Server (which is free) and will perform far better than a spreadsheet. It will also be far more robust. I have lost data in spreadsheets in several projects, especially with many rows & columns. In the past 20 years I have never lost data in SQL Server.